# How to stage files only in one branch?

Tags: git

Say I'm on master and I want to save some changes (modified and untracked files) for later but without using the stash command (I'm used to `stash` and `pop` things I try really quick). And since these changes are intended to be an important change I rather want to "save" this initiated change on its own branch.

How can I do that ?

---

Here is an example workflow with unexpected *(for me)* results..

1. `#(master)# git status`
   `On branch master`
   `nothing to commit, working tree clean`
2. `#(master)# git touch b.txt`
   `#(master)# git status`
   `On branch master`
   `Untracked files: b.txt`
   `Nothing added to commit but untracked files present`
3. `#(master)# git checkout -b branch`
   `Switched to a new branch 'branch'`
   `#(branch)# git status`
   `On branch branch`
   `Untracked files: b.txt`
   `Nothing added to commit but untracked files present`
4. `#(branch)# git add .`
   `#(branch)# git status`
   `On branch branch`
   `Changes to be committed: new file: b.txt`
5. `#(branch)# git checkout master .`
   `Switched to a branch 'master'`
   `#(master)# git status`
   `On branch master`
   `Changes to be committed: new file: b.txt`
   → Isn't this change only staged
   in the other branch?
6. From now if I want to go back to the previous state of the master branch I can:

   1. remove this file by deleting it. So, I expect to have a clean master branch but instead I got the following:
      `#(master)# rm b.txt`
      `#(master)# git status`
      `On branch master`
      `Changes to be committed: new file: b.txt`
      `Changes not staged for commit: deleted: b.txt`
      → Why git saw the changes made on the other branch? Isn't the staging area (the index) a per-branch area?
      → Why git saw the deletion as a change since it has not been even committed?
   2. <s>clean with the</s> `clean -fd` <s>command..</s>
      Nope, that doesn't work since the file is not untracked anymore even on master..
   3. <s>using the</s> `reset` <s>command (either with `--HARD` or bydeleting the file afterward).</s>
      Nope, that removes (and lose) also the file from the staging area (as expected indeed).

---

I thought I knew (at a basic level) how git branches work.. But it seems not.. So how can I stage modifications in a per-branch basis?

I know that I could achieve what I want with stashing or actually committing the changes.

About stashing I'm just afraid about losing the changes with an accidental `pop`.
And regarding an actual commit, I just didn't want to commit that initiated modifications which are in an intermediate state and not ready at all.
In fact I could then `--amend` that commit.. Maybe this is the only solution..

Thank you for your precisions..

Answer (score 1):

Branches are indeed only at the commit level, since branches are just pointers to commits.

Staging is just a process of selecting changes that will be included in the commit. It is entirely agnostic of the branch that is currently checked out.

If your commits are small enough and frequent enough, stashing shouldn't scare you, as you would only be keeping that stash for a short while. For longer periods, I would indeed create a commit and then either amend it, or create a bunch of commits and then rebase as I see fit.

Comment: Since I don't know when I'll continue that feature, stashing is not a good option. But I should definitely think about commits being a mean to save works. I could even do what I want in my repo and then maybe rebase as you suggested.. Yes this makes sense.. I just need to learn more about `rebase`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Between steps 4 and 5 you should have made a commit to permanently record the staged changes in the repository. Other than that, your approach seemed sensible.

> Isn't this change only staged in the other branch?

> Isn't the staging area (the index) a per-branch area?

No, there is only one index. It is not specific to a particular branch.

---

> 6. From now if I want to go back to the previous state of the master branch

If you had made the commit after step 4, the commit graph would look like this:

```
...--o--o--A [master]
            \
             B [branch]
```

Where `A` is the latest commit on the branch `master` that existed at step 4, and `B` is the new commit that you made after step 4, while the branch `branch` was checked out.

Commit `B` would contain the new contents of `b.txt`, while commit `A` would not.

Step 6 would now simply become a matter of checking out the branch `master`.

Comment: Thank you, yes I should consider commits more as a mean to save my works (unless pushing the works) than a definitive record..